# Folding over an ITree

Tags: haskell

Given the following `ITree`, from [Typeclassopedia](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Functor):

`data ITree a = Leaf (Int -> a) | Node [ITree a]`

What's the proper signature for `foldTree` - fold over the entire tree?

Here's my incorrect attempt that does **not** compile:

```
foldTree :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> ITree a -> b
foldTree f (Leaf x)  = f x []
foldTree f (Node xs) = f _ $ map (foldTree f) xs
```

However, passing an empty list for the `Leaf x` case seems odd to me.

Also, in the second pattern match for `Node`, I don't know how I can apply an `a` since I don't have one due to: `Node [ITree a]`.

Comment: Are you missing some prime marks? I can't type-check your code.

Comment: I just updated my question. Sorry - the code does not compile since I don't know what to pass into `f`'s first argument.

Comment: This tree contains stuff of type `(Int -> a)`. There is no way to get an `a` out of such thing if you don't have an `Int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to figure out the reasoning behind your `foldTree` signature.

According to the [Foldable section of the Typeclassopedia](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Foldable) the generic fold operation has one of the following signatures:

```
class Foldable t where
  fold    :: Monoid m => t m -> m
  foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m

  foldr   :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
  foldl   :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> t b -> a
  foldr1  :: (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a
  foldl1  :: (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a
```

It also says that the others may be derived from either `fold` or `foldMap`.

Let's try to figure out what `foldMap` has to be for an `ITree a`.

From the signature:

```
foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> ITree a -> m
foldMap f (Leaf x) = ???
```

it's clear that the only way to create an `m` is to apply the combining function `f` to some `a`. But the only way to get an `a` from a `Leaf x` is to apply `x` (which is a function) to some `Int` like this:

```
foldMap f (Leaf x) = f (x 0)
```

Here we've chosen to evaluate `x` at 0, but any integer constant will work.

For the `Node` case, this seems like the only possibility:

```
foldMap f (Node ts) = mconcat [ foldMap f t | t <- ts ]
```

That is, we fold over all of the trees given us a list of `m` values, and then use `mconcat` to reduce that to a single `m`.

To summarize, all that is happening with this definition of `foldMap` is:

1. Start with an `ITree a`
2. Evaluate all of the leaf nodes at some constant.
3. Now you have a conventional tree of a values.
4. Perform a standard fold on that tree.

Comment: I just want to highlight that evaluating all the leaf nodes at some constant is deeply fishy at best. But there's no way around it in the context of a fold. I'd say, as GHC does with `DeriveFoldable`, that `Constructor 'Leaf' must not contain function types`.

Comment: Also, in keeping with the Typeclassopedia theme, you could use `<$>` from `Functor` to replace the list comprehension in the second equation for `foldMap`: `mconcat $ foldMap f <$> ts`

Comment: I totally agree that evaluating the leaves at an arbitrary value feels wrong - I just wanted to demonstrate what following the types lead to.

Comment: why is it that `any integer constant will work`? For the signature `Int -> a`, how do you know that the `Int` is meaningless, i.e. doesn't affect the `a` output?

Comment: The choice of the integer _does_ affect the output.

Comment: @KevinMeredith As user5402 said, it does affect the output. Consider a function `f n = n`. That function (and most that match that signature) will produce a different value for each possible integer argument. There's actually some really interesting stuff behind how polymorphism affects the possible implementations of a function, but in this case it can do basically anything. There's no reason to use one particular integer constant over any another here though, since we don't know anything about how the `Int -> a` function works.